# Current way to query mongodb by date using vertx mongoclient

Tags: java, mongodb, vert.x

I want to fetch all the documents from a collection having a field named "updatedOn" less than or equal to a certain date.

I am using the below code snippet.

```
Date date = new Date(2018, 12, 2);
JsonObject q = new JsonObject().put("updatedOn", new JsonObject().put("$lte", date));

mongoClient.findBatch("mycollection", q)
            .handler(r -> {

                System.out.println(r);

            })
            .endHandler(endr -> {
                System.out.println("end reached.");
            });
```

Unfortunately, the above code snippet throws an exception

> "Illegal type in JsonObject: class java.util.Date" at JsonObject q = new JsonObject().put("updatedOn", new JsonObject().put("$lte", date));

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Chances are the JSON is being put through the [extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) parser of the Java Driver. You would therefore need a JSON object with the `$date` key and a value either as an ISO string or numeric.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, use the extended JSON format:

```
String date = "2018-12-02T00:00:00+00:00"
JsonObject q = new JsonObject().put("updatedOn", new JsonObject().put("$lte", date));

mongoClient.findBatch("mycollection", q)
            .handler(r -> {

                System.out.println(r);

            })
            .endHandler(endr -> {
                System.out.println("end reached.");
            });
```